# Looking for clarification on Hashing and BST functions and Big O notation

Tags: c++

So I am trying to understand the data types and Big O notation of some functions for a BST and Hashing.

So first off, how are BSTs and Hashing stored? Are BSTs usually arrays, or are they linked lists because they have to point to their left and right leaves?
What about Hashing? I've had the most trouble finding clear information regarding Hashing in terms of computation-based searching. I understand that Hashing is best implemented with an array of chains. Is this for faster searching or to decrease overhead on creating the allocated data type?

This following question might be just bad interpretation on my part, but what makes a traversal function different from a search function in BSTs, Hashing, and STL containers?
Is traversal Big O(N) for BSTS because you're actually visiting each node/data member, whereas search() can reduce its time by eliminating half the searching field?

And somewhat related, why is it that in the STL, list.insert() and list.erase() have a Big O(1) whereas the vector and deque counterparts are O(N)?

Lastly, why would a vector.push_back() be O(N)? I thought the function could be done something along the lines of this like O(1), but I've come across text saying it is O(N):

```
vector<int> vic(2,3);
vector<int>::const iterator IT = vic.end();

//wanna insert 4 to the end using push_back

IT++;
(*IT) = 4;
```

hopefully this works. I'm a bit tired but I would love any explanations why something similar to that wouldn't be efficient or plausible. Thanks

Comment: by `hashing` do you mean hash table?

Answer (score 1):

BST's (Ordered Binary Trees) are a series of nodes where a parent node points to its two children, which in turn point to their max-two children, etc.  They're traversed in O(n) time because traversal visits every node.  Lookups take O(log n) time.  Inserts take O(1) time because internally they don't need to a bunch of existing nodes; just allocate some memory and re-aim the pointers. :)

Hashes (unordered_map) use a hashing algorithm to assign elements to buckets.  Usually buckets contain a linked list so that hash collisions just result in several elements in the same bucket.  Traversal will again be O(n), as expected.  Lookups and inserts will be amortized O(1).  Amortized means that on average, O(1), though an individual insert might result in a rehashing (redistribution of buckets to minimize collisions).  But over time the average complexity is O(1).  Note, however, that big-O notation doesn't really deal with the "constant" aspect; only order of growth.  The constant overhead in the hashing algorithms can be high enough that for some data-sets the O(log n) binary trees outperform the hashes.  Nevertheless, the hash's advantage is that its operations are constant time-complexity.

Search functions take advantage (in the case of binary trees) of the notion of "order"; a search through a BST has the same characteristics as a basic binary search over an ordered array.  O(log n) growth.  Hashes don't really "search".  They compute the bucket, and then quickly run through the collisions to find the target.  That's why lookups are constant time.

As for insert and erase; in array-based sequence containers, all elements that come after the target have to be bumped over to the right.  Move semantics in C++11 can improve upon the performance, but the operation is still O(n).  For linked sequence containers (list, forward_list, trees), insertion and erasing just means fiddling with some pointers internally.  It's a constant-time process.

push_back() will be O(1) until you exceed the existing allocated capacity of the vector.  Once the capacity is exceeded, a new allocation takes place to produce a container that is large enough to accept more elements.  All the elements need to then be moved into the larger memory region, which is an O(n) process.  I believe Move Semantics can help here as well, but it's still going to be O(n).  Vectors and strings are implemented such that as they allocate space for a growing data set, they allocate more than they need, in anticipation of additional growth.  This is an efficiency safeguard; it means that the typical push_back() won't trigger a new allocation and move of the entire data set into a larger container.  But eventually after enough push_backs, the limit will be reached, and the vector's elements will be copied into a larger container, which again has some extra headroom left over for more efficient push_backs.

Answer (score 0):

Traversal refers to visiting **every** node, whereas search is only to find a particular node, so your intuition is spot on there. O(N) complexity because you need to visit N nodes.

`std::vector::insert` is for insert in the middle, and it involves copying all subsequent elements over by one slot, inorder to make room for the element being inserted, hence O(N). Linked list doesnt have this issue, hence O(1). Similar logic for `erase`. `deque` properties are similar to `vector`

[std::vector::push_back is a O(1) operation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/), for the most part, only deviates if capacity is exceeded and reallocations + copy are needed.